# Calculating new attribute based on condition using Field Calculator in QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, field-calculator, attribute-table, fields-attributes, qgsexpression

I have a shape with different city areas that contains the average building heights (`"HHO-mean"`) in meters. Now I want to categorize the average building heights in a new column in five different categories (1-5).

I tried the following:

```sql
CASE
    WHEN "HHO_mean" > 5.7 THEN 1
    WHEN "HHO_mean" > 6.4 THEN 2
    WHEN "HHO_mean" > 7.1 THEN 3
    WHEN "HHO_mean" > 8.0 THEN 4
    WHEN "HHO_mean" > 10 THEN 5
END
```

and

```py
if( "HHO_mean" > 5.7, '1', if( "HHO_mean" < 6.4, '2',  if( "HHO_mean" < 7.1, '3', if( "HHO_mean" < 8.0, '4', if( "HHO_mean" < 10, '5', '0')))))
```

In both cases the new column only contains 1 in every field. Any suggestions?

Comment: If all values are above 5.7, they all fulfill the first condition. The calculator is did his job and goes home. You could either revert the conditions (check for the largest one first) - though I don't know if this works - or include a check for a ceiling, e.g. `if ("column" > 5.7 AND "column" <= 6.4)`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your query you forgot to include the upper edge for your range of values. It is possible with using an [AND](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_and_or.asp)-operator.

So, try:

```sql
CASE
   WHEN "HHO_mean" > 5.7 AND "HHO_mean" <= 6.4 THEN 1
   WHEN "HHO_mean" > 6.4 AND "HHO_mean" <= 7.1 THEN 2
   WHEN "HHO_mean" > 7.1 AND "HHO_mean" <= 8.0 THEN 3
   WHEN "HHO_mean" > 8.0 AND "HHO_mean" <= 10 THEN 4
   WHEN "HHO_mean" > 10 THEN 5
   ELSE 0
END
```

The same issue appears in `if()`, therefore it has to be `if("HHO_mean" > 5.7 and "HHO_mean" < 6.4, '1', ...`.

*Note:* The [BETWEEN](https://www.essentialsql.com/use-operator-compare-range-values-sql-server-queries/)-operator unfortunately is not implemented in QGIS's Field Calculator.

---

**References:**

- [SQL Comparison operator](https://www.w3resource.com/sql/comparison-operators/sql-comparison-operators.php)

Answer (score 6):

the order of the condition check is value_if_true then value_if_false

so in your second test, it should be (note the >= instead of > on the first condition):

```
If( "HHO_mean" <= 5.7, '0', if( "HHO_mean" <= 6.4, '1', if( "HHO_mean" <= 7.1, '2', if( "HHO_mean" <= 8.0, '3', if( "HHO_mean" <= 10, '4', '5')))))
```

Answer (score 3):

The case will end when first `when` is true, so with your case expression all values above `5.7` will be classified to `1`.
You just need to change the order of the whens from highest to lowest:

```
CASE
    WHEN "HHO_mean" > 10 THEN 5
    WHEN "HHO_mean" > 8.0 THEN 4
    WHEN "HHO_mean" > 7.1 THEN 3
    WHEN "HHO_mean" > 6.4 THEN 2
    WHEN "HHO_mean" > 5.7 THEN 1
END
```

Comment: Thank you for additional information ^_^